# I'll see you a few days later

Tags: error

*I'll see you a few days later.*

The above sentence is supposed to be wrong. The correct alternative is "I'll see you in a few days". What's wrong with the exemplary sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the example sentence itself.   It's a perfectly natural sentence, and I'd use it if given the right context.   For example:

> I plan to start traveling soon after the first of the month.   ✓I'll see you a few days later.

The context is important.   For "a few days later" to make sense, we have to know *what* these few days are later *than*.   In the context above, I'll see you a few days later than the start of my travels.

Without a related context, the sentence doesn't make sense:

> My name is Gary.   ✗I'll see you a few days later.

Later than *what*?   Later than my name, perhaps?   There's nothing in the context that allows the word "later" to make sense.

The sentence "I'll see you in a few days" is not dependent on context for its meaning.   Not only is the sentence good, it still makes sense in the absence of any context:

> My name is Gary.   ✓I'll see you in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds odd doesn't it? I'm not sure it's more than just irregular/informal [future perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_perfect).

I will see you…

- <sup>?</sup>**a few days later**.
- **a few days from now**.
- **in a few days**.
- **a little later**.
- **sometime later**.
- **later**.

I believe 'few days later' is mismatching a tense or a clause that isn't presented by 'will see you'.

- We saw each other **a few days later**.
- It happened **a few days later**.
- <sup>?</sup>I should do it **a few days later**.

Answer (score 0):

The only time you would say "a few days later"  is if you pushed your appointment out.

> We were supposed to meet tomorrow, but I will see you a few days later ( than tomorrow)

Hope this helps!